# Add margin-left, script inside php

Tags: javascript, php

The problem is. I want to inset margin-left: 20%; to maincontent, when the user is logged in.

No i dont have a problem with syntax, i can get it done in js, but im told to use php.
So i also added a class in css and to my body.

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['username']){


include("/view/leftmenu.php");

}
?>
```

How do i activate css in php?

Comment: You need to learn basic PHP syntax. `'<script` opens a string, and then you terminate it prematurely with `$('#main...`.

Answer (score 4):

As revealed by the syntax highlighting, you're trying to put a single quote inside a single-quoted string.

Your options are:

1. Escape the single quotes with `\'`.
2. Use double quotes instead.
3. Use `?> ... <?php` instead of `echo`.
4. Don't do this with JavaScript at all!  You control the server side; why not just add a class to the body like `logged-in`, and have a CSS rule like `body.logged-in #maincontent { margin-left: 20%; }`?

(For what it's worth your JavaScript is invalid too; you need to quote the `20%`.  Percentages aren't legal JS.)

Comment: I don't get your point in 4. I know what you mean, but how do i then add the class from php

Comment: the same way you're adding a script now, but with `class="whatever"` instead of a whole script tag  :)

Comment: So. Add a class in css, inset class="loggedin" in php if statement, and tag my body with loggedin?

Comment: yes, though please don't edit your question to be about something radically different...

Answer (score 1):

Put your JavaScript in double quotes, with single quotes inside. You may want to run your `include` first as well. `include` does not need `()`. Your code could look more like:

```
<?php
session_start(); // has to be run before any headers are sent
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  include '/view/leftmenu.php';
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#maincontent').css('margin-left', '20%');</script>";
}
?>
```

The better solution however would look more like:

```
<?php
session_start(); $marginLeft = '0'; // $marginLeft should be your default
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  $marginLeft = '20%';
  include '/view/leftmenu.php';
}
echo "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style type='text/css'>".
"#maincontent{margin-left:$marginLeft;}</style></head><body>".
"<div id='maincontent'>content</div></body></html>";
?>
```

A better approach yet, would look like:

```
<?php
session_start(); $className = 'withoutMargin'; // $marginLeft should be your default
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  $className = 'withMargin';
  include '/view/leftmenu.php';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type='text/css'>
      .withoutMargin{
         margin-left:0;
       }
       .withMargin{
         margin-left:20%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
<?php echo "  <div class='$className'>"; ?>
  <!-- your content here -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: Your code above does not have to look exactly like this. This just illustrates concept. You would have more code testing for submit to be set and so forth. Also, with the second example, which I recommend, I would use external CSS, so it is cached by the user's Browser.

Comment: The other guy says i should do it in php and add a css class

Comment: Now you can see what that means.

Answer (score 0):

20% needs to be in quotes:

```
$('#maincontent').css('margin-left', '20%');
```

This also applies to px, em, pt, and any other form of CSS unit of measurement.